# Creating custom site on IIS 7

Tags: php, iis-7, web

I have IIS 7 running on Windows 7. Everything works fine with the default website. Now I am trying to create a new site with physical path `C:\users\xxx\mysite`.
I am following [this tutorial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

The site is created but when I run it, I get the following error:
    **HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
    The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.**

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: Good lord, you should get some unix server software and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got this working!
There was nothing wrong in the configuration.

I was **windows file permissions** issue.

To fix this I did the following:

1) In IIS, click edit permissions (on the right side).

2) Go to Security tab.

3) Click Edit -> Add -> Advanced -> Find Now.

4) Select both IIS_IUSRS and IUSR.

5) Click OK>OK>OK... and exit

That's it!